# Undefined Movie Name and City Name in Seats HTML Template Despite Passing Through JavaScript and URL in Django Application

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-views, django-urls

this is my html code of shows.html

```
{% for cinema_hall in cinema_halls %}
    <div>
        <h2>{{ cinema_hall.name }}</h2>
        <div class="show-container" id="show-container-{{ cinema_hall.id }}">
            <!-- Loop through shows for each cinema hall -->
            {% for show in shows %}
                {% if show.cinemahall == cinema_hall %}
                    <div class="show-box" data-cinema_hall_id="{{ cinema_hall.id }}" data-show_id="{{ show.id }}">
                        Show: {{ show.timings }}
                        <br>
                         ₹ {{ show.price }} 
                    </div>
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

and this is its js code

```
    function filterShowsByDate(date) {
        const movieName = '{{ movie_name }}'; // Replace with actual movie name
        const city = '{{ request.GET.city }}'; // Replace with actual city name

        $.ajax({
            url: `/shows/${movieName}/filter/${date}/?city=${city}`,
            type: 'GET',
            success: function(response) {
                // Clear existing show containers
                $('.show-container').empty();

                // Loop through the filtered shows and display them
                response.shows.forEach(function(show) {
    const showBox = `<div class="show-box" data-show-id="${show.id}" data-cinema-hall-id="${show.cinemahall_id}">Show: ${show.timings} <br> ₹ ${ show.price } </div>`;
    $('#show-container-' + show.cinemahall_id).append(showBox);
});


                $('.show-box').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // Prevent default behavior
    
    const showId = $(this).data('show-id');
    const cinemaHallId = $(this).data('cinema-hall-id');
    const movieName = $(this).data('movie-name');
    const cityName = $(this).data('city-name');
    
    // Redirect to seats page with appropriate parameters
    window.location.href = `/seats/?show_id=${showId}&cinema_hall_id=${cinemaHallId}&movie_name=${encodeURIComponent(movieName)}&city_name=${encodeURIComponent(cityName)}`;
});
                 


            },
            error: function(xhr, errmsg, err) {
                console.log(errmsg);
            }
        });
    }
```

and this is views.py

```
def filter_shows_by_date(request, movie_name, selected_date):
    selected_city = request.GET.get('city')
    
    # Filter shows based on movie name, city, and selected date
    shows = Show.objects.filter(movie__name=movie_name, city__name=selected_city, date=selected_date)
    
    # Prepare data to be sent as JSON response
    shows_data = list(shows.values())

    response = {
        'movie_name': movie_name,
        'shows': shows_data,
        'selected_date': selected_date,
    }

    return JsonResponse(response)


def seats(request):
    show_id = request.GET.get('show_id')
    cinema_hall_id = request.GET.get('cinema_hall_id')
    movie_name = request.GET.get('movie_name')
    city_name = request.GET.get('city_name')

    # Retrieve show details
    show = Show.objects.get(id=show_id)

    # Retrieve cinema hall details
    cinema_hall = CinemaHall.objects.get(id=cinema_hall_id)

    context = {
        'show': show,
        'cinema_hall': cinema_hall,
        'movie_name': movie_name,  # Pass movie name
        'city_name': city_name  # Pass city name
    }

    return render(request, 'screen/seats.html', context)
```

and this is urls.py

```
  path('shows/<str:movie_name>/', views.shows, name='shows'),
  path('shows/<str:movie_name>/filter/<str:selected_date>/', views.filter_shows_by_date, name='filter_shows_by_date'),
 path('seats/',views.seats, name='seats' ) ,
```

now what want is that when user click on respective show div its get directed to seats.html , which is working good , but in seats.html i want, it to show movie, in front of movie , city in front od city and etc
this is the seats.html code

```
 <p> 
        Movie name: {{ movie_name }} <br>
        City: {{ city_name }} <br>
        Cinema hall: {{ cinema_hall.name }} <br>
        Date: {{ show.date }} <br>
        <!-- Add other relevant show information here -->
    </p>
```

and i am not getting things here and in url also the movie name and city name are undefined, so please help me

Comment: what does the URL linking to seats say?